# If $G$ is a group and $g \in G$ has order $n_{1} n_{2}$, $1=\gcd(n_{1},n_{2})$, then there exists...

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Problem:**  If $G$ is a group and $g \in G$ has order $n_{1} n_{2}$, $1=\gcd(n_{1},n_{2})$, then there exists elements $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ such that $|g_{1}|=n_{1}$, $|g_{2}|=n_{2}$, and $g=g_{1}g_{2}=g_{2}g_{1}$.

The obvious choices for our elements ($g_{1}=g^{n_{2}}$, etc.) didn't work. Then, I tried playing around with cute ways to factor $n_{1}n_{2} + 1$ (adding/subtracting terms, etc.). This also didn't work. Finally, I looked at the prime factorizations of $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$. Now, I'm here asking for help.

Comment: Use the fact that $1=sn_1+rn_2$ for some $s,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ with  $n_2\nmid s$ and $n_1\nmid r$ to choose $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=an_1+bn_2$ by Bezout.

Comment: Use $a$ and $b$ suggested by @Hagen to see that $g_1=g^{bn_2}, g_2=g^{an_1}$